# C# report data refresh when text changed

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

how can i make my Report to refresh report data when TextBox text changed?

```
     private void LetoviIzvjestajForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource ="eProdaja.Izvjestaji.LetoviIzvjestaj.rdlc";
      }


       private void txtNazivLeta_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<esp_Let_Izvjestaj_Result> ds = DALet.SelectLetByName(txtNazivLeta.Text);
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```

And it works when i type one letter i got result. But when i type more letters result in report does not change.

RESOLVED!

```
private void txtNazivLeta_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (ds.Count != 0)
            {
                ds.Clear();

                ds = DALet.SelectLetByName(txtNazivLeta.Text);
                ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

            }
            else
            {

                ds = DALet.SelectLetByName(txtNazivLeta.Text);
                ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

            }


        }


    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the particular API being used here, but it looks like every time the text is changed, you're creating a new data source and adding it to a list without removing/clearing the previous data source(s).  Could that be the problem?

Comment: tnx i resolve my problem with this